# Como al adjuntar un archivo en un formulario (hecho en html) se guarde en google drive

Tags: google-drive

Tengo un formulario creado con HTML y CCS y tiene un apartado para adjuntar un archivo.

Cuando envian ese formulario los datos se guardan en una SpreadSheet de Google, pero el archivo no se me guarda.

Lo que quiero es que cuando rellenen el formulario y lo envíen, el archivo se suba/guarde a una carpeta de Google Drive y en la hoja del SpreadSheet me ponga un enlace a esa archivo que esta guardado en Google Drive.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola, cree un formulario y necesito que la persona que lo llene adjunte una imagen, y esa imagen se guarde en drive, ya cree el acceso para adjuntar la imagen pero no se como se puede guardar en drive

Comment: @MariaIsabel podrias editar la pregunta y poner el codigo que utlizas.. tanto el HTML como el JAVASCRIPT y la funcion gs de appscript, para entender mejor